# Bones, weight painting and very weird deformations

Tags: rigging

I'd just like to be able to assign an object to a bone and have it be 100% controlled by that bone.  Surely this is possible without the weight painting business. Its so easy to miss a vertex or two somewhere, and then I end up with these long stretchy deformities when I set a pose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Enter edit mode for the armature and select the bone you want to be the parent. Go back to object mode.

Select the object to be the child, then shift select the armature.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and select Bone. You can't choose which bone here, it will be set to the bone that was selected when the armature was in edit mode.

[image]

You can verify the settings under the Object Properties - Relations

[image]

You can choose to set these properties manually but you may need to re-position the object afterwards.